# Big JS app testing - avoiding multiple karma.conf.js files

Tags: javascript, testing, gruntjs, karma-runner

I use **karma** + **jasmine** + **phantom** for my headless Javascript tests.

The problem I have is that I have a really big app consisting of a lot of JS modules which I want to test. **So I need custom mocks for each case and custom includes for each case.**

`karma.conf.js` allows me only to have `files` array which consist of patterns for all the files to include which is GREAT if my app would be small and not a big app with ton of files and modules.

**My solution** for now - create multiple `karma.conf.js` files for each test case. But this really sucks as having so lot of config files is a big bloat and if I would want to change one setting(like *autoWatch*) I would need to change all the config files.

My **other solution** - write custom handler in front of `karma.conf.js` to handle additional parameters(spec file or folder to bypass karma for searching it's config file) and simply build `files` array dynamically.

Now the problem I see with this is that karma runs only once and I would be limited to run one test spec... and **I DO NOT WANT TO MODIFY KARMA ITSELF**.

I have also considered using **Grunt** but haven't found a way to make it work for multiple test cases.

*By the way, my ideal structure would be like this:*

to have files:

```
test/specs/category/unit1_spec.js
test/mocks/category/unit1_mock.js
```

config file:

```
files: [
  {
    'includes': [array_of_includes],
    'spec': 'spec_file'
  }
]
```

mock file would be grabbed automatically from appropriate mocks directory.

and I could do `karma start test/specs/category` and it would recursively run all the test cases inside the folder.

**tl;dr - I want to test comfortably a big app.**

**I would appreciate *any* suggestion to handle this task.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[grunt-karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma) sounds ideal for your needs.

It is a grunt multitask which allows sub tasks to have a common configuration, which can be overridden by specific sub tasks.

The plugin consolidates Karma configuration into a single file.
For example:

```
karma: {
  options: {
    configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
    runnerPort: 9999,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox']
  },
  category1: {
    files: ['app/js/category1/**/*.js', 'test/category1/*.js']
  },
  category2: {
    files: ['app/js/category2/**/*.js', 'test/category2/*.js']
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me.  If I use "files" under each module, I end up with an error of "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'src' in <my file path>".  If I use "src" instead of "files", it runs but those files are never pulled in for the tests.  Any thoughts?  I created a post on this yesterday.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467715/grunt-karma-not-running-the-spec-file-when-using-shared-config

Answer (score 17):

Use an ENV variable to pass the argument to files in karma.conf.js:

```
files: [
  include1, include2, ..., includeN,
  process.env.JS_TESTS + "/*.js"
]
```

Then run karma like so:

```
JS_TESTS=test/category2 karma start karma.conf.js
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use require statements in karma config files.

for example, in your karma config file you could do:

```
files: require('./karma.conf.files')
```

For a fuller answer .. I found another solution from this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/karma-users/uAf7TuVBmCQ

**With karma 0.8 (current stable)**

```
// shared_conf.js
module.exports = {
  port: 8080
};

// karma1.conf.js
var shared = require('./shared_conf.js');

port = shared.port;
```

**With karma 0.9 (currently in canary release):**

```
// shared_conf.js
module.exports = function(karma) {
  karma.configure({
    port: 8080  
  });
};

// karma1.conf.js
var shared = require('./shared_conf.js');
module.exports = function(karma) {
  shared(karma);
  karma.configure({
    // override
  });
};
```

This worked for me to pull in an array of file names from a separate config file.

Comment: With karma 0.13, it's `config` that is exposed, not `karma`: `module.exports = function(config) { config.set({ files: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }) }`. Then in `karma1.conf.js`, apart from having `config.set` method, you can read `config.files` and all other values and modify them.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that whatever argument you pass into command line you get this argument camelCased in initial config object.

```
> karma start i-wanna-debug

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        singleRun: config.iWannaDebug ? false : true
    });
};
```

This allows you to use single Karma config file with multiple configurations.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. In dev, I'd test with multiple browsers but in VSTS I'd only want to test with PhantomJS. Instead of having two different config files, each in dev and testing environment, I have the same in both

Comment: Small hint: `karma start i-wanna-debug` does not work for me, I had to prepend `--`, like `karma start --i-wanna-debug`. Btw, a single dash `-` allows to pass single character flags, like `karma start -iwd` while `i` and `w` and `d` are treated separately.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed no answer for 2022, so here it is:

1. Require your base `karma.conf.js` and save into a const.
2. It returns a function you can call, so call it on your config first.
3. Then apply any overrides.

Final code can look similar to this:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  const baseConfig = require('../karma.conf');
  baseConfig(config);
  config.coverageReporter.dir = require('path').join(__dirname, '../../../coverage/my-lib_secondary');
};
```

In my case I needed all code coverage reports to appear in one folder, from the main app, the library and its secondary endpoint. App is using Angular 14.